# Elasticsearch for each record to match all other records in one query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm using elasticsearch holding all active users.

For example, if I have 200 active users and for each user I want to find all users that within 300km.

In order to find matches for each user I need to run the following function 200 times.

```
findOneMatch(UserID) {
  /*
     elastic search query here to find any user within 300km
  */
}
```

Is it possible to have one query and find all matches for each single user?

The result I want would be:

```
User 1: (matches: User 5, User 15, User 23)
User 2: (matches: User 25, User 115)
User 3: (matches: User 33, User 44, User 55)
User 4: (matches: User 44, User 66, User 115)
...
```

Not looking for specific query but directions

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @apokryfos I need find matches for each user to everyone else, I can do it with a for loop to go through 200 users and find matches for each of them. I wonder can I do this in one query and be faster?

Comment: Can you share the kind of search query you will need to do 200 times? Perhaps seeing it will help show what you need to do.

Comment: @apokryfos I updated with examples... should be clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

You can leverage multisearch API. What it does is, you can combine search queries for all your users into one and then fire them at once, you will receive a bulk response which will contain search results for every query that was part of the multi-search.

Be careful to avoid overwhelming the server with the number of queries in your batch.